# Development software - How common is it for developers to buy it for personal use

Tags: visual-studio-2008, development-environment

Edit: The answer is yes, pretty common. The Microsoft TechNet is one of best deals (except it does not have Visual Studio). So MSDN generally is a better choice. Thank you

Hello All,
I was recently looking at prices of Microsoft Visual Studio, SQL server and MSDN subscription. I never considered it necessary to buy it for personal use, until this year. For some reason it is not possible to get any new hardware, operating systems or development tools at my work. Everything I can use for self-training of pet projects is on average 5-10 years old. So I am seriously thinking of buying my personal software. The company I work for is one of the largest in USA, but for last few years R&D is non-existent. And I have spent all possible trial periods for Microsoft Visual Studio, SQL Server and similar things. I never mind to spend hundreds of dollars for broadband, personal computers, technical books. But Development Software ?

So I need to hear from you. How many of you, being full-time employed by software shops decided to spend cash on things, your employer will never buy for you: things like Visual Studio, laptops, Windows 7 etc.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to find a new job before they run out of money for other totally essential things, such as your salary. :-x

Comment: Exactly. But first I need to gain some marketable skills. Personally I am sick of Java/J2EE, and I am really interested in C#, .NET, but never had an opportunity to start and complete any meaningful project in C#. Having one or two C# projects going live I will definitely will start looking for new job.

Comment: Well, you mention you are wanting to learn more c# / .net.  I took a class at a local community college and Microsoft offered free software including SQL Server 2008 Enterprise and Visual Studio 2008.  The 5 credit class was under $500.  Also, if you live in Seattle or near, You can get free Visual Studio by attending a usability session.

Comment: Well, it might be a very nice deal for some people. But it has  drawbacks: it costs time, its not online, its not usable for profit. Also I would be shy of sitting in class with young people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also get a [Technet subscription](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/default.aspx).  With it you can download most of the software you'll need and it's really inexpensive.  I think it's a perfect fit for you.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the Technet looks like a perfect fit.

Comment: Just be aware that the licencing between TechNet and MSDN is different. It may not matter in your situation, but do spend some time and read the fineprint.

Answer (score 3):

Ask yourself this question: how many trades people buy their own tools? Answer: pretty much all of them.

You do not need an expensive MSDN subscription for most of your dev work. There are free versions of Visual Studio available that will do 99% of what you need. There are free versions of SQLServer (look for the Express versions). The only thing the MSDN subscription will give you is access to the operating systems, plus lots of other stuff you probably will never use (although it also gives you Office, which can be handy).

You can get cheaper access to MSDN if you participate in either the BizSpark or or WebSpark programs.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know about all this Microsoft deals. The Technet subscription looks like the best for me.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft makes a lot of free tools available that allow you to accomplish what you need to.  I've been building web sites for a while now using [Visual Web Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/) expression edition and [Visual C#](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/Default.aspx) expression edition along with [SQL Server 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/Default.aspx).

For most side/home/research projects, these tools are sufficient.

There are other open source options as well, such as [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/), but I've found the express editions from Microsoft to be much more stable.

If you are looking to start a business on the side, however, these tools are not sufficient.  If you are looking to become an ISV and use Microsoft tools for development, you can enroll in [BizSpark](http://www.microsoftstartupzone.com/pages/home.aspx).  If you are building web sites, there is a parallel program called [WebSiteSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/).  Both of these programs give you access to Microsoft tools and technologies equivalent to MSDN *for free* for a limited period of time (3 years or a certain revenue benchmark).  The only caveat is that once you are out of the program, you need to compensate Microsoft $100.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you. Express Edition was great for me few years ago to get a feel of C#. But just today I tried to build some portion of source code and found the Express Edition useless without ATL. Its just an example how far free tools can let you go. 

Nice, BizPark and WebSitePark are being mentioned here. But its for someone starting their own business, not for cubicle hamster like me.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I've bought Visual Foxpro, Visual studio 2003, and Expression blend.  If you can attend conferences and launch events you can sometimes pick up free copies for personal use.  Another alternative is to take an evening class somewhere so you can get the student discount for a personal copy to learn on.

Comment: Thank you. I know about that students get better deals with Microsoft. Good to know that it is a practical way to obtain the tools. But I am afraid it makes the tools unusable for any commercial use.

Answer (score 2):

You can enroll in a single tech class at your local university -- most of them partner with Microsoft and will give you all of that stuff for free if you're a student.

Answer (score 1):

When I work as a contractor (freelancer), I buy my own development tools whenever I think I need them. As an employee, never ever.

Comment: Agree, it applies to the most of normal situations, when obsolescence of tools is below some critical point.

Answer (score 0):

Startup a company to build something and then get [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/) for $100 after 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

I pay my own money for an [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com) license every year.  I use it at home for my own projects.

Comment: Nice. Thank you for mentioning the real fact of spending. 

Btw, I was browsing the local job market today and discovered this little company. My search was: "joelonsoftware" -> "jobs" -> "jet the company" -> "products" -> "ItelliJ" -> "forums" -> "complains about CPU hogging". Sickly familiar java memory options and people's pain with garbage collection of GBs of ram. After using Eclipse and couple of similar IDEs, I will not handle one more of java based IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick fyi, if you're not on Windows you can give [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) a shot, I really enjoy using it for personal use at home where I have an older laptop running linux.

If Windows OS is your final choice though, I would also suggest the Technet subscription, I think it offers good value.

Comment: Thank you. My friend, who develops a lot in C#, have recommended me Mono/Linux a year ago. But he also uses Studio Professional at his work himself. I have used Visual Studio 6 many years ago and since then got impression that none of community projects can compete with commercial tools. Except may be one example, like Eclipse IDE. But for Eclipse there must be some special explanation. May be it is  sponsored by IBM or something.

Comment: I agree that community tools don't have as steady a stream of updates and version changes compared to commercial tools, and sometimes lack business level support, but none the less they do offer great value and utility especially for training or pet-project work. Best of luck!